# How do I setup a windows folder to get backed up when a thumb drive gets installed?

Tags: windows-10, backup, usb-flash-drive

I'm running into some issues whenever I start open office, so I'm thinking about removing the wear, and tear on my thumb drive by keeping the files local then backing up to a thumb drive. How would I setup a trigger on a thumb drive to back up files anytime it gets inserted into the USB slot?

As I'm transitioning out of IT into theology for publishing it would be appreciated if you include pictures.

Comment: See this>>>>https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/automatically-backup-usb-drive-when-plugged-in.html

Comment: I want a step by step method without downloading a tool (folder style), because it should be built into windows, because I remember an event backup on previous versions of windows.